# SQL Server 2005 - SQL Statement to remove clustered keys from tables based on a query on tablenames?

Tags: sql-server, navision, dynamics-nav

I am trying to restore a backup of a Microsoft Dynamics NAV database, which unfortunately fails as it tries to set a CLUSTERED KEY for the tables which already have clustered keys.

In NAV, every company in the database gets its own copy of the tables, prefixed with the Company's name, e.g. `COMPANY$User_Setup`. I'd therefore like to remove any clustered key on a given company, which means on any table which name starts with 'Company$'.

Has anybody got a SQL statement that could perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do it as a cursor. Assuming each PK constraint is named consistantly and is based on the table name, you'd be able to do something like (untested, so may contain typos or vauge syntax errors):

```
DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sysobjects WHERE name LIKE 'Company$%'

OPEN CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @tablename
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE QUOTENAME(' + @tablename + ') DROP CONSTRAINT PK_' + @tablename 
    EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @sql
    FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @tablename
END

CLOSE CURSOR
DEALLOCATE CURSOR
```

If your PK's aren't named based on tablename, then you'll have to modify this to also query based on sysconstraints or sysindexes to get the actual PK name.

Comment: That won't do it - you're just removing the Primary Key constraint - that's not dropping the index yet. Furthermore, while the primary key typically is the clustered index by default, this is not a requirement - it could be two different indices. And even more: the primary key (if it's the clustered index as well) usually also is referenced by foreign key relationships - so those would have to be dropped, too, before you can drop the primary key index.

Comment: Normally dropping the PK constraint will also drop the associated index. 

However, I admit to making some assumptions for keeping it simple ... but to illustrate the basis of a solution, it does provide a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware I'd be dropping the primary key. In fact, I'd just reset CLUSTERED to HEAP on the index. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: No - you'd have to drop and recreate the index.

If the columns are the same in all tables (which it sounds like it is as you've said they get a copy of tables), then you can just extend the cursor loop to create the non-clustered (unique?) index on-the-fly after it's dropped the constraint.